# Unity3d Drawing curves to show the angle between vectors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to show interactively the angle between two vectors in Unity3D. For example,

[image]

I need to draw the curve between the "vectors" and show the numeric value in degrees. I know how to calculate the angle, but got no success on how "draw" the curve between them. I tried to use Bezier Curves, but no success either.

Comment: http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer something totally different.

You can try and go with Beziers or Catmull-Rom but it would make it more complex when you can achieve this more easily.

Place circle UI image at the origin of the angle. Then set the type to filled and clockwise.

Now you have the slider indicating the amount, just match it with the angle with

```
Image image = GetComponent<Image>();
image.fillAmount = GetAngle() / 360f; // Range is 0/1 so you need normalization
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/Manual/script-Image.html